# Images from picasaweb on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, picasa

I need work with images from picasaweb on Rails (add, delete, view). I tried some gems (picasa, etc). But gem and json return only albums, images array is empty.

Comment: Do you have projects where you implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this gem with example:

```
require "picasa"

# get some photos in an album
client = Picasa::Client.new(user_id: "your-gmail-account@gmail.com", access_token: "oauth-access-token")

albums = client.album.list.entries
album = albums.find { |album| album.title == "New Album" }

photos = client.album.show(album.id).entries

photos.each { |photo| puts photo.title }
```

> [https://github.com/morgoth/picasa](https://github.com/morgoth/picasa/blob/master/examples/get_some_photos.rb)
>
> https://github.com/morgoth/picasa/blob/master/examples/get_some_photos.rb